# Mysql Where clause as a parameter

Tags: mysql

This is what i'm trying to do.

```
  begin
    set @WhereClause = '1=1'
    select * from tblDealerships where @WhereClause;
    end
```

I thought it would be simple but it's not.

Comment: you want you use CASE here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Prepared Statement to include expressions from variables.

```
begin
    set @WhereClause := '1=1';

    set @sql := concat( 'select * from tblDealerships where ', @WhereClause );

    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    drop prepare stmt;
end  ;
```